# d3.js BMI graph, creating curved reference lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a graph in d3 that is a scatter-plot of a persons weight in kg(x-axis) vs height in cm(y-axis) to show their BMI.

I have the graph working, showing each person as a dot with their appropriate height and width.

I would like to create reference lines like the graph here:
[image]

Where the dark red line is where BMI is 30. BMI is calculated as (weight / (height(m)^2).  I can work on filling under the line after I get the lines drawn but for right now, I am just trying to figure out how to have the lines drawn.

One solution I considered was to create 10,000 random points between the max height value and the min height value and calculate a weight associated with each of those randomly generated height values where the BMI would equal 30. Then sort them and plot a line going through those points. Thus creating a pretty good approximation of where the function should be.

That however, seems like a non-ideal solution.

Does anyone know a way to more simply create a reference line that is based on a function:

`30 = x / (y * .01)^2`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You'll have to sample. See [this post](https://pavpanchekha.com/blog/plotting-d3.html).